# error when using categorical variable with Tune SVM in R

Tags: r, svm

When I want to use the `tune()` function, I get an error saying that my response variable must be numeric for regression.

I have defined `Type = "C"` but then the error is of definition problem.

```
obj <- tune(svm, clasifica~., data = SUPERVISADO, scale=FALSE, type="C",
            ranges = list(gamma = 2^(-1:1), cost = 2^(2:4)),
            tunecontrol = tune.control(sampling = "fix")
)
```

```
 Error in svm.default(x, y, scale = scale, ..., na.action = na.action) : 
      Need numeric dependent variable for regression.
```

```
Error in tune(svm, clasifica ~ ., data = SUPERVISADO, scale = FALSE, type = "C",  :  Dependent variable has wrong type!
```

Answer (score 0):

`y` needs to be a factor for classification. See `?svm`.

Note the call to `factor()` in this minimal working example inspired by your code:

```
library(e1071)

tune(svm, factor(vs) ~ ., 
     data = mtcars, 
     scale = FALSE, 
     ranges = list(gamma = 2^(-1:1), 
     cost = 2^(2:4)),
     tunecontrol = tune.control(sampling = "fix"))
```

Output:

```
Parameter tuning of ‘svm’:

- sampling method: fixed training/validation set

- best parameters:
 gamma cost
     1    4

- best performance: 0.2727273
```